# Track click on a Visualforce component that plays a video

Tags: visualforce-component, google-analytics

I am trying to figure out how to track (send to Google Analytics) when a user clicks to play a video that is referenced in a Visualforce page (below).

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="DisplayTopFiveNewestMembersForPortal" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0" applyBodyTag="False" applyHtmlTag="False">
<style type="text/css">
    body {
    background-color: white;
    center;
    }
</style>

<video align="center"  valign="center" width="500"  preload="metadata" controls="true" oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload"> 
    <source src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686A000005nkvY" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686A000005nkvY" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the `<video>` element that is triggered by a [play event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event). Note that the play event is fired automatically if the `autoplay` attribute is set to true.

```
<video align="center"  valign="center" width="500"  preload="metadata" controls="true" oncontextmenu="return false;" controlsList="nodownload" id="my-video"> 
    <source src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686A000005nkvY" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686A000005nkvY" type="video/ogg"/>
</video>

<script>
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('my-video');
    videoPlayer.addEventListener('play', function(event) {
        //debugging
        alert("The video is starting to play");

        //Google Analytics code here
    };
</script>
```

Comment: nbrown - you were a huge help!  I am now successfully tracking video on a VF page in GA.

Comment: I am not trying to do the same thing when calling a Youtube video via iFrame...the trigger that should recognize it in Tag Manager isn't picking up when video is played.  Thoughts?
                                <iframe src="{!'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+v.VideoURL2+'?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0'}" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: That is not so simple. You can only detect when someone's focus is in an iframe or not as anymore than that could lead to security vulnerabilities. I would refer to Google Tag's documentation, as there should be a way to track YouTube videos like this blog details: https://www.lovesdata.com/blog/tracking-youtube